# Detect Quicktime plugin withOUT using Javascript

Tags: quicktime

Is it possible to detect the existence of the Browser's Quicktime plugin withOUT using Javascript?

I know how to test for Quicktime using Javascript, but not without.

My logic says that Javascript can be enabled/disabled by the user and the existence of the Quicktime plugin is determined by the programmers for each Browser.  Therefore, each should an independent statistic ... even for Apple's iOS which has Quicktime built in.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am really throwing away my question. However, I thought some of you might be curious why ...

I honestly do not know if it is possible to detect the existence of the Browser's Quicktime plugin withOUT using Javascript. I do know, for example, that Quicktime is built into Apple's current OS and probably many prior ones.

Nevertheless, I have come across the expression "***Progressive Enhancement***". As a direct result, I have discovered the works of others that result in my being okay with detection of Quicktime using Javascript.

The following illustrates what I mean:

The way-back-when driving force was to avoid `document.write` in the display of media players for .mp3, .m4a and the like.

The new approach places the media player, the no-js message, and the no-qt message in the html markup.

The default case is to show just the no-js message in the **html markup**. Using the "***Progressive Enhancement***" paradigm, if Javascript is enabled, then Javascript is used to first hide the no-js message. Depending on the presence of Quicktime, we then show the media player and hide the no-qt message, or vice versa. As a result, we progress from a "vanilla" text message about no Javascript to showing a media player if Quicktime is present.

For example, my **html markup** presents:

```
<section class="mediaWrapper">
    <div class="mediaplayer">       
<audio name="aMedia" class="aMedia" controls preload="auto"
       src="audio/My Love Song Forever.mp3">    
    </div>

    <div class="nojs">
Turn on Javascript to hear an awesome Love Song
    </div>

    <div class="noqt">

<a href="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
   title="Get Quicktime"
   onclick="window.open(this.href); return false">
Install Quicktime
</a>
 to hear an awesome Love Song

    </div>
</section>   <!-- mediaWrapper -->
```

**In my `<head>` is this `<style>`:**

```
/* default settings for the html markup */
.mediaWrapper {
    display:    block;
    position:   relative;   
    text-align: center;
}

.mediaplayer {
    display:     none;
}

.nojs {
    display:     block;

    font-size:   110%;      /* for the no-js alert text */
    color:       #360;
    font-weight: bold;          
 /*
    text-align:  center;    // inherited from .mediaWrapper
 */
}

.noqt {
    display:     none;

    font-size:   110%;      /* for the no-qt alert text */
    color:       #360;
    font-weight: bold;          
 /*
    text-align:  center;    // inherited from .mediaWrapper
 */
}
```

**Also in the `<head>` is this `<script>`:**

```
$(document).ready (function() {

    $('.nojs').hide();   // we're here, already!

    if (QuicktimeIsPresent)
    {
        $('.mediaplayer').show();
        $('.noqt').hide();  
    }
    else
    {
        $('.mediaplayer').hide();
        $('.noqt').show();  
    }

});   // $(document).ready
```

As already stated, the **html markup** (via the above **`<style>`**) shows just the vanilla no-js message. Via ***Progressive Enhancement***, if Javascript is enabled, then the above `<script>` is seen. So, Javascript is used to first hide the no-js message. Depending on the presence of Quicktime, we then show the media player and hide the no-qt message, or vice versa.